# is there a "rails" way to redirect if mobile browser is detected?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile, user-agent

I want to run a user-agent check but only on my homepage (static_controller#home)  I have taken a close look at the code: http://www.arctickiwi.com/blog/mobile-enable-your-ruby-on-rails-site-for-small-screens and it seems close but it never gets tied together, its just method creation...  I am open to a jquery method but would prefer ruby/rails over js.

I only really care about iphone and droid...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices). They suggest using the following for detecting a mobile device:

```
request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
```

Comment: This fails on tablets and several other types of mobile browsers. Check my answer below for a gem solution.

Answer (score 4):

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Extremely useful for me.

Answer (score 4):

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219949/detecting-mobile-browsers-in-rails-3):

The best way is to use some supported plugin/gem, like [browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser)

This is much better than writing your own regex.

For example Opera 11.50 has the following user_agent:

`Opera/9.80 (Android 2.3.7; Linux; Opera Mobi/ADR-1111021303; U; en-GB) Presto/2.9.201 Version/11.50`

The suggested regex of:

`request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/`

would total miss that.

You also get the benefit of knowing what platform (mac, windows etc), tablets, ie6 etc. I am a rookie rails dev, I set it up and got it working in like 2 minutes. Highly recommended.

Comment: Excellent gem. Still very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/neighborland/mobu

> Mobu provides a Rails controller concern called DetectMobile. Mobu does server-side User Agent detection to categorize requests as mobile, tablet, or default.
>
> Mobu modifies your rails view paths based on the request type. It does not require custom MIME types or separate subdomains.