# Server-Side Device Detection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What are Rails developers doing to detect device details on the server? There seem to be a few old WURFL libs, but nothing recently.

I'm using responsive design and want to avoid sending out images that will be hidden anyway, since browsers display them. (There are some client-side workarounds like using background-image, but they make the client unnecessarily complex.)

Detecting width would be particularly useful, as it corresponds to Bootstrap and similar responsive frameworks.

Comment: Detect if mobile question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905765/is-there-a-rails-way-to-redirect-if-mobile-browser-is-detected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the open source (last tab is rails example). http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: Thanks, useful lib, but it only detects if mobile or not. Ideally looking for width (udated question to clarify.)

Comment: I doubt there is an open source/easy way to get that info on server side. Once I heard DeviceAtlas (paid service) provides that kind of information, but I never used my self. http://deviceatlas.com/

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party here, but we do have a WURFL Cloud Client in Ruby that may meet your needs.  http://www.scientiamobile.com/cloud

Answer (score 0):

Another open source detection software you might want to check out would be [51Degrees.mobi](http://51degrees.mobi?CATReferrer=1765). They have PHP, C and a few other implementations you might find useful.