# Image resizing for mobile site, Ruby on rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

so I am working on a website that is a static scrollable one page, but for some reason it was deployed in ruby on rails. I am a noob in ror.
There is one image in the html page that needs to resize whenever the site is loaded on a mobile device.

```
   <li><%= image_tag 'Main_logo.png', width: '700', height: '399' %></li>
```

Now I think I can do this in CSS, which means the client will resize and the full size image will always be downloaded. My question is how can I solve this issue using ror? I am sure ruby on rails has some server side capacity to fix this. Keep in mind I am new to ruby on rails

Thanks.

Comment: Is your problem detecting mobile browsers? Or is it resizing on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your problem of resizing images, you can use the gem `rmagick` (https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick)

The key line you probably need is `thumb = img.resize_to_fit(75, 75)`, and the document explaining it well is at http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/comtasks.html

To your problem of detecting mobile browsers: SO post [Detecting mobile browsers in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219949/detecting-mobile-browsers-in-rails-3)

Or if you want a super quick and dirty way, you can paste this into your controller:
http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: Leave a comment if you need some specific help!

Comment: thanks for this, I am kinda new to ROR, all my app has is a single webpage called home.html.erb under app-views-pages, and some css files under app-assets-stylesheets. Now I have an image tag in my original question to identify the image, how do IO use that with rmagick? do I need to do that in the controller? Model?

Comment: See if Ryan Bate's Screencast will help you understand Rmagick better; he can do a whole lot more explaining than I can :) http://railscasts.com/episodes/374-image-manipulation